# Non invasive method of identifying web application users

Tags: security, ip, user-experience

I'm building a web application that allows users to report on traffic delays. I would like for users to be able (if at all possible) to create reports without signing up nor signing in, but also to prevent abuse by users introducing non useful data by limiting the amount of reports a unauthenticated user can create.

Is this possible without cookies or storing IP addresses?

My reasoning is the less friction to create a report the more willing users will be to make one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use captchas to stop automatic posting and discourage users from mass submission (solving captchas is no fun after some time). But if that is too intrusive there is not much left to work with without IP addresses. Think about the interface at a low level. Even assuming you would allow cookies, a user sends a GET request to your server to get a valid session id (or cookie state in a more generalized setting) and later on sends a POST request to your server containing the cookies and the report. There is nothing that allows the server to differentiate between a thousand users each following the above once and one user following the above a thousand times.

Thus I'd say: No, you have to live with the risk of attacks and possibly filter them out on a statistical level or implement some IP address based throttling.